# Drupal 7 - Add attributes to views anchors in theme/template file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

Typically views appear to output anchors without 'title' attributes.

How would you add 'title' attributes and any other attributes to anchors through either template suggestions or the theme template?

There doesnt appear to be any good documentation on this and we dont want to use the admin/CMS to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the output and rewrite it as a link.  From here it will allow you to input a title option.

Also you can create a template file and manually produce these attributes.

Comment: The html is rendered before it gets to the template stage. How would you produce the attributes if this is the case?

Comment: Do you know how to create a template file from a view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105740/drupal-7-views-which-type-of-output-to-use-for-re-render-of-link

Comment: Yes i do.  Do you need still need help with this or is it resolved?

Comment: This is resolved now, I didnt know you manipulate the $fields variable just before the loop. Thanks for your input Chad.