# Drupal 7 Views: Which type of output to use for re-render of link

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

When selecting theming information in views what type of output will enable me to re-render the links? The links require title attributes and the views gui is not an option.

- Display
- Style
- Row
- Field

Comment: Please, provide an example of what you are trying to do. I cannot understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: Used 'Row output' as the theme suggestion and manipulated the $fields variable before looping its properties.